# Why is my submit button not working on this form I made in PHP?

Tags: php, html

This one's really stumped me and it's for something that should be relatively simple. I am trying to make a form with nothing but a submit button in the middle of a table I am echoing in PHP. The name of the submit button in this form is being drawn from a database I have a working connection to.

I have tested thoroughly and can confirm the data is coming from the database. I have a couple of other similar forms working fine in the page and they work correctly. When I put this particular form next to those working ones, it works fine. Besides that, I can't get this form to work anywhere else.

Here's the code for my broken form, along with context:

```
function buildTables($thecategory = "staff")
{
    include "db.php";
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB');        

    $stmt = $mysql->query($_SESSION['query']);
    $customercount = 0;
    $totalpoints = 0;
    $paythismonth = 0;

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
    {
        echo'<table><tr><article style="line-height: 0.5em; padding-bottom:2em; background-color:FF7070; color: white; height: 20em; width: 100em; margin-left: 14em">
        <div style="display: table-row; color: white">
        <div style="display: table-cell; padding-left: 2em; padding-top: 2em">
        <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.8em">'.$row['Forename'].' '.$row['Surname'].'</p>
        <p>ID: '.$row['ID'].'</p>
        <p>Forename: '.$row['Forename'].'</p>
        <p>Surname: '.$row['Surname'].'</p>';

        if ($thecategory == "staff")
        {
            echo  '</div><div style="display: table-cell; padding-left: 20em; padding-top: 2em"><br><br><p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em">Emergency Contact</p>
            <p>Forename: '.$row['Emergency Forename'].'</p>
            <p>Surname : '.$row['Emergency Surname'].'</p>
            <p>Address Line 1 : '.$row['Emergency Address Line 1'].'</p>
            <p>Address Line 2 : '.$row['Emergency Address Line 2'].'</p>
            <p>City: '.$row['Emergency City'].'</p>
            <p>Country: '.$row['Emergency Country'].'</p>
            <p>Postcode: '.$row['Emergency Postcode'].'</p>

            #BROKEN FORM HERE
            <form action="editstaff.php" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Edit staff member" style="font-size: 1.2em" name="'.$row['ID'].'" /></form></div>'; 
        }
```

And here's the place elsewhere in my table where I *can* get forms to work.

```
    if ($thecategory == "customers")
    {
        $customercount+=1;
        echo '</div><div style="display: table-cell; padding-left: 20em; padding-top: 2em"><br><br>
        <p>Points: '.$row['Points'].'</p>';
        $totalpoints += $row['Points'];
        $averagepoints = $totalpoints / $customercount;
        echo '
        <form action="editcustomer.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Edit customer" style="font-size: 1.2em" name="'.$row['ID'].'"></form>
        <form action="removecustomer.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Remove customer" style="font-size: 1.2em" name="'.$row['ID'].'"></form></div>';
    }
```

Just to confirm, this exact sort of code works completely fine elsewhere in my website but here it does not. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's the entire HTML output of the page:

```
<head>
    <title>Manager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gamerz-Music.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <font face="Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif></font>
</head>


<style>

body {
    background-image: url("blank.png")
}
</style>


<div class="header">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="">

    <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="#Home">Home</a> 
        <a href="/2018-ac32006/team7/games.php">Games</a>
        <a href="/2018-ac32006/team7/music.php">Music</a>
        <a href="/2018-ac32006/team7/tvandmovies.php">TV/FILM</a>
        <div class="search-container">
            <form action="/action_page.php">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
                <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br><br><br>


<div class="Pop" style="width: 1em; position: fixed; margin-top: 4em">
    <form method = "post">
        <input type="submit" name="staff" value="View all staff" style="font-size: 1.2em; background-color: pink; height: 3em; width: 10em">
        <input type="submit" name="customers" value="View all customers" style="font-size: 1.2em; background-color: pink; height: 3em; width: 10em; margin-top: 1em">
    <form>
</div>

<br>CATEGORY = staff<br><table><tr><article style="line-height: 0.5em; padding-bottom:2em; background-color:FF7070; color: white; height: 20em; width: 100em; margin-left: 14em">
            <div style="display: table-row; color: white">
            <div style="display: table-cell; padding-left: 2em; padding-top: 2em">
            <p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.8em">William Shatner</p>
            <p>ID: DI3446</p>
            <p>Forename: William</p>
            <p>Surname: Shatner</p><p>Role: Technician</p>
                <p>Date of Birth: 1931-03-22</p>
                <p>Date Employed: 2015-02-04</p>
                <p>NI Number: OO502044N</p>
                <p>Hourly Salary: £10.20</p>
                <p>Hours This Month: 40</p><p>Pay so far this month: £408.00</p>
                <p>Contact Number: 07987345197</p></div><div style="display: table-cell; padding-left: 20em; padding-top: 2em"><br><br><p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em">Contact Details</p>
            <p>Address Line 1 : 48 Victoria Road</p>
            <p>Address Line 2 : </p>
            <p>City : Bath</p>
            <p>Country: UK</p>
            <p>Postcode: BA56 2SY</p></div><div style="display: table-cell; padding-left: 20em; padding-top: 2em"><br><br><p style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em">Emergency Contact</p>
                <p>Forename: Leonard</p>
                <p>Surname : Nimoy</p>
                <p>Address Line 1 : 98 East Street</p>
                <p>Address Line 2 : </p>
                <p>City: Cambridge</p>
                <p>Country: UK</p>
                <p>Postcode: CM6 0WT</p>
                <form method="POST" action="editstaff.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="DI3446">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></form></div></article></tr></table><br>
</body>

<div class="footer">
        <a href="Sam">Facebook Page</a>
        <br>
        <a href="Location"> Dundee DD1 4LA</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The `action` methods in a working one and in the broken one look suspitiously different. Also i would advise against echoing that much html code. The same result can be achived easier. PHP code can be inserted to the html markup. And it will be executed on the server side.

Comment: Can you confirm if the `$row['ID']` is correct Id that you want to edit. Also can you elaborate the issue like what's the exact error?

Comment: Can you confirm all the values your trying to echo out in PHP do actually exists.

Comment: putting row['ID'] as a variable name is a very bad idea. try to read code from the editcustomer.php with print_r($_REQUEST); and say what is shows.

Comment: By this time $row['ID'] should evaliate to a single name, number, whatever it is. Depends on the Database structure. I am more interested in what variable `$_SESSION['query']` holds inside itself. I have a feeling the query fails and `$stmt->fetch()` returns `false`

Comment: Yeah the code itself is pretty sketchy but works fine in other parts of the website. All query information is being returned. Was hoping to simplify this question to just the form itself not working

Comment: `<table><tr><article` — Your HTML is invalid and invalid HTML tables cause **massive** problems, especially when mixed with forms. Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/) and don't use tables for layout. 1996 has come, we have CSS now.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone. I've come to accept, as I was ready to, that this broken button is simply punishment for my terrible code and I will have to omit it from my implementation. HTML is definitely not my favourite language.

Answer (score 0):

The question is simple. In order to submit a form you have to put your button between `<form></form>` tags like below:

```
<form method="POST" action="your_file.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value=".$row['ID'].">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

A better approach by putting a tag like:

```
 <a href="your_file.php?ID=".$row['ID']."&action=edit">edit</a>
 <a href="your_file.php?ID=".$row['ID']."&action=remove">remove</a>
```

Comment: As  far as I see tags are not the proplem. The tags are there. They are inside the giant echo.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that awful echo. But still no luck. Clicking on the submit button does nothing.

Comment: can you put a code from browser's html output? (ctrl-u or rightclick show page source)